Inequality between the coefficients of complex polynomials
Let $P(z) = a_nz^n + \dots + a_0$ and $Q(z) = b_mz^m + \dots + b_0$ with $n < m$. Assume all the roots of $Q$ lie in the unit disk and that $|P|\le|Q|$ on the unit circle. Is it true that $|a_n| \le |b_m| - |b_0|$?
From the maximum principle applied to $\frac{P}{Q}$ outside of the unit disk, it is clear that $|a_n| \le |b_m|$. However, it is not obvious to me what effect $b_0$ has, or how to even involve it in the inequality.
